# Where should I post this question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I tried to post [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36189/whats-the-most-used-2-digits-abbreviation-system-for-mexican-states) on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), but a user answered me it was not appropriated for that site.

Where should I post the following question, as it is not a question about programming, nor travel, nor culture properly:

> *What's the most used 2-digits abbreviation system for the names of mexican states?*
>
> I'm coding a health system which should offer a menu containing the
>   list of mexican states (and DF) in a patients' creation section.
>
> I know there is [RENAPO](https://renapo.gob.mx/swb/swb/RENAPO/renapo)'s standard, but it differs from other
>   standards, as you can see in this [Wikipedia's article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantilla:Abreviaciones_de_los_estados_de_M%C3%A9xico), and I
>   don't know which standard is the best to use.
>
> Which 2-digits abbreviation standard is more used to identify a
>   mexican state as part of an address or a person birthplace?

Comment: For the record, my best idea is still Expatriates. Perhaps regulars over there can give some insight as to whether my instinct is good.

Comment: Also, this is probably as good a time as any to point out that I don't think you mean "two [digits](https://www.google.com/search?q=digit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=define:digit)" but "two [characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_%28computing%29)" or maybe even "two letters". This is probably a translation issue.

Comment: Possibly English L&U?

Comment: @haykam I don't think so. The question is which abbreviation is most used...seems to be language independent.

Comment: Considering [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64665/address-form-field-for-region/64702#64702), maybe UX would be appropriate?

Comment: @called2voyage That's an answer. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more thought, I'm not sure Expatriates is best since (I presume) you are not an expatriate yourself. However, your question definitely strikes me as a user experience (UX) related question, and so the only obstacle to overcome is finding someone in that field who knows the details for Mexico state abbreviations. Consider the accepted answer to the following question at [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/):

[Address form, field for "region"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/64665/51758)

It seems there might be someone over there with the requisite knowledge after all.